Why can't I get Discord to redirect to my flutter project?
I'm trying to implement the Discord sign-in function in my Flutter app, but whenever I select the Discord button to sign in, I keep getting the error "invalid OAuth2 redirect_uri."
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<queries>
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" />
</queries>

<application
    android:label="one_bet"
    android:icon="@mipmap/tournament_launcher">

    <!-- Facebook SDK Configuration -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                   android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>

        <!-- Main launcher intent -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Twitch OAuth Redirect Deep Link -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="Oasis" android:host="auth" android:path="/twitch" />
        </intent-filter>
      
        <!-- Discord OAuth Redirect Deep Link -->
        <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="Oasis" android:host="callback" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />

</application>

</manifest>
LoginPage.dart
LoginProvider(
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.discord,
                  callback: () async {
                    try {
                      debugPrint('Start Discord sign in');

                      // Initialize the AppAuth and authorization token request
                      final FlutterAppAuth appAuth = FlutterAppAuth();
                      final AuthorizationTokenResponse? result =
                          await appAuth.authorizeAndExchangeCode(
                        AuthorizationTokenRequest(
                          '1288183304121483326', // Replace with your Discord client ID
                          'https://oasis-gameapp.web.app', // Replace with your redirect URI
                          serviceConfiguration:
                              const AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
                            authorizationEndpoint:'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize', // Discord auth URL
                            tokenEndpoint:'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', // Discord token URL
                          ),
                          scopes: [
                            'identify',
                            'email'
                          ], // Add other scopes as needed
                        ),
                      );

                      // Check if the result is not null, meaning login was successful
                      if (result != null) {
                        debugPrint('Discord sign in successful');
                        debugPrint('Access Token: ${result.accessToken}');
                        debugPrint('ID Token: ${result.idToken}');
                        debugPrint('Refresh Token: ${result.refreshToken}');
                        return result
                            .accessToken; // Return the access token or handle login success
                      } else {
                        debugPrint('Discord sign in canceled or failed');
                        return null;
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      debugPrint('Error during Discord sign in: $e');
                      return null;
                    } finally {
                      debugPrint('Stop Discord sign in');
                    }
                  },
                ),

ive create a small html file that is hosting on firebase hosting and the Discord redirect just fine ,Please remember im still learning about Oauth2...Help!!
